# Highlight flagged messages in Mac Mail App

Tags: macos, mail.app

**How can you automatically highlight messages that are flagged with additional background coloring?**

- The mail app has a tiny flag in the top right of the message, but it doesn't really draw attention.

**Current Appearance:**
[image]

---

**Desired Appearance:**
[image]

- This thread https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252536582?answerId=254778777022#254778777022 states that a rule can be used, but I don't see an option to choose "flagged" messages.  This used to be native behaviour in previous versions of Mac mail (don't recall the version).
- Do not want to go into format/colors each time as this would require flagging and manually coloring as I still was to use the flag filters.

***Technical Details:***

- macOS Monterey v12.5
- Mac Mail v16.0

Comment: You don't have rule for flagging? You add flags manually? If you use rules for flagging then you can set flag as well as background color in same rule.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg Correct, no rules.  I flag things for follow up and I don't know a priori which ones will be important.

Comment: If you flag manually (⌘+⇧+L) then you can set background color in same way using keyboard shortcut ⌘+⇧+C. You can always customize Mail view so that flag is displayed more noticeable way.